# Generating a Sphinx document with a blockdiag diagram without title pages

Tags: python-sphinx, documentation-generation, pypi

I am trying to use Sphinx to generate a blockdiag diagram with an accompanying description table, as described in the example under "desctable" [here](http://blockdiag.com/en/blockdiag/sphinxcontrib.html?highlight=sphinx%20extension) in the blockdiag documentation.  I set up a very simple sphinx project; there is nothing in the main .rst file except for:

```
.. blockdiag::
   :desctable:

   blockdiag {
      A -> B -> C;
      A [description = "browsers in each client"];
      B [description = "web server"];
      C [description = "database server"];
   }
```

When I run "make latexpdf", it generates a PDF file with the desired diagram and description table.  However, it also generates a lot of unnecessary pages, including a title page, filler pages, and an empty table of contents.

**My question is this: Is there a way to get rid of the filler pages?  All I want is the diagram and description table, on a single page, with nothing else in the pdf.**

The less formatting/headers/footers/filler stuff, the better.  I would avoid using Sphinx but the description option in blockdiag only seems to work with Sphinx.

Disclaimer: I am a complete newbie to Sphinx (just started trying it an hour ago).  Also, I couldn't figure it out from the Sphinx documentation, but perhaps I'm just not searching the right terms.

Any help would be greatyl appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.  In conf.py, I just needed to set

```
latex_elements = {
'maketitle': '', 
'tableofcontents': '',
}
```

This removes all the filler pages I wanted to get rid of.